# Nginx regex to point both subdomains and domains to same root directory

Tags: regex, nginx

Here are a few example of urls:

1. http://www.customer.com
2. http://customer.com
3. http://customer.com.dev.company.com

This is what I'm using right now that is working for 1 and 2:

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
root /var/sites/$domain; # this goes to /var/sites/customer.com
```

I also want to be able to point nr 3 to the same root folder, but this regex i've tried is not working (it works with nr 3 only):

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)(\.dev\.company\.com)$;
root /var/sites/$domain; # i want this to also go to /var/sites/customer.com
```

Comment: Are these the only sites on the server / nginx instance ?

Comment: I have multiple websites on the server in /var/sites/ and using the same nginx config to point the domain to the /var/sites/domain. I dont want to maunally create new configs every time I create a new website. dev.company.com is the same always

Comment: Try: `~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+?)(\.dev\.company\.com)?$` - make the named capture less greedy and the last capture optional.